# Lithophane goes flat when in edit mode - Please Help!

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-printing

I am in the process of earning how to create Lithophanes AND I'm very new to Blender.

With all that said, last night I was able to play with the model in edit mode, this morning everything is flat in edit mode.

I really hope this is a simple fix, this is happening on both of my computers. Please help I really don't want to give up on this.

[image: Object_Mode]

[image]

Comment: This is completely normal. When you apply displacement through a _Displacement_ node in the _Shader Editor_, this is an effect applied on the object upon rendering, it is not working on the original mesh - but that is which you are working on in _Edit Mode_. Or if you are using a _Displacement_ modifier, _Edit Mode_ will also show the base mesh upon which the modifier is working - unless you enable the "Edit Mode" and "On Cage" options in the modifier. But these are just guesses - unfortunately you don't provide any information on how you did the displacement.

Comment: Your comment helped me more than you know. Knowing that it was from the displacement (added as a modifier) i was able to find the option that was unchecked for some reason on both of my machines. 

Now i'm able to see that in the displacement modifier the 4 options next to the title bar is "Edit Mode", i turned this back on and everything was good. I don't know how they were unchecked but i'm happy they are now! 

Thank you again!

Comment: Well, "unchecked for some reason" - usually this is unchecked by default, because a lot of people are trying to tweak the original mesh rather than a (procedurally and not "real") modified mesh.